# Graphql ruby how to create interface type and implement it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql

I have follow this [docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rmosolgo/graphql-ruby/GraphQL/InterfaceType) about to create and implement interface on graphql:

here is my code:

```
PaymentInterface = GraphQL::InterfaceType.define do
  name 'Payment'

  field :name, types.String
  field :grand_total, MoneyType
  field :subtotal, MoneyType
  field :shipping_fee, MoneyType
end
```

and this is the object type that implement previous interface

```
PaypalPaymentType = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
  interfaces [PaymentInterface]

  field :paypal_charge do
    type -> { MoneyType }
    type types.String
    resolve lambda { |obj, _args, _ctx|
      Hashie::Mash.new(
        currency: obj.currency,
        price: obj.paypal_charge
      )
    }
  end
end
```

Here is the query:

```
interface PaymentInterface {
    name: String
    grand_total: MoneyType
    subtotal: MoneyType
    shipping_fee: MoneyType
}
type PaypalPaymentType implements PaymentInterface {
    name: String
    grand_total: MoneyType
    subtotal: MoneyType
    shipping_fee: MoneyType
    paypal_charge: MoneyType
}
{
  purchasables {
    isService
    isProduct
    price
    ... on PaypalPaymentType {
      paypal_charge { raw formatted }
    }
  }
}
```

But Im keep getting error, anyone has the same experience before? thanks in advance

```
GraphQL::Schema::InvalidTypeError (Field PaymentMethod.paypal_charge is invalid: name must return String, not NilClass (nil)):
```

Comment: What kind of error is it that you are getting?

Comment: @tpei updated my question

Answer (score 0):

In here you are defining twice the type of the field:

```
PaypalPaymentType = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
  interfaces [PaymentInterface]

  field :paypal_charge do
    type -> { MoneyType } # <--- Defined type as Money Type
    type types.String # <--- Overwritten defined type as String
    ...
  end
end
```